# Implementing the insert array method for a hand-written dynamic array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, size, allocation

So my code is supposed to take a dynamic array and inserts a smaller array into it and if there's not enough space in the larger array then it makes a new array and copies the values from the old array into the new one so that the smaller array can be inserted. Here's the code that allocates the new size for the new array with dynamic_array &a being the smaller array and i  being the position it's inserted to:

```
void dynamic_array::insert(dynamic_array &a, int i) {

    if (i < 0 or i > size){
        throw exception(SUBSCRIPT_RANGE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    int *new_array;
    int range = a.get_size(); //my get size method will return how many values are in a
    int blocks_needed = (size) / BLOCK_SIZE;
    if (size % 5 > 0) {
        blocks_needed = blocks_needed + 1;   //add a block if needed
    }   

    if (size + range >= allocated_size) { //new space needed
        //get more space
        try {
            new_array = new int[blocks_needed * BLOCK_SIZE]; 
        } catch (bad_alloc){
            throw exception (MEMORY_EXCEPTION);
        }
```

Then there's 3 different for loops. One copies all the elements before i-1. The second copies all the elements in array a. The third one copies all the remaining elements from the old array into the new array while shifting them over:

```
    //copy array[0..i-1]
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        new_array[j] = array[j];
    }

    //copy a
    for (int m = i; m < range; m++){
        new_array[m] = a[m];
    }

    //copy array[i..size-1]
    for (int k = i; k < size; k++) {
        new_array[k+range] = array[k];
    }
```

Afterwards I update the sizes:

```
size = size + range;
allocated_size = blocks_needed * BLOCK_SIZE;
```

Now if there is already enough space then I just shift the array to the right and insert the values via a for loop:

```
else { //no new space needed
        shift_right(i, size, range);
        for (int z = i; z < range; z++){
            array[z] = a[z];
        }
        size = size + range;
    }
```

Now the output I'm getting is quite close to what I want however it's not quite what I want. There's alot of times where the array values show things like `0 3 0 2 4` when it should show `0 1 3 2 4`. The allocated size is also sometimes wrong when it shows that it's 5 when it should be 10. The size looks fine for all tested arrays but it's just the allocated size and the array values that's the problem. Here's my shift right function:

```
void dynamic_array::shift_right(int start, int end, int delta){
        for(int i=end; i>=start; i--){
            array[i+delta] = array[i];
        }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Unless this is homework your bug is probably related to the fact that you aren't using `std::vector`.

Comment: I've noticed one mistake so far, in the second for loop, should be
`for (int m = i; m < range; m++) { new_array[m] = a[m - range]; }`

Comment: Also, I think it would be better to paste the whole `dynamic_array::insert()` method code uninterrupted, with comments in the code or with line numbers or some markers in the code for comments to point to.

Comment: It might also make sense to post `dynamic_array::shift_right()` implementation here.
Other than that, you have a **much** higher chance of us fixing this code when you provide concrete examples of input, expected output, and received output.

Comment: @user657267, I have to disagree, homework or not, using `std::vector<>`  eliminates the need to write this code altogether, which I guess is being written for learning purpose.

Comment: @iksemyonov I think you mean `new_array[m] = a[m - i]`. You should put it in an answer, as that is most likely the OPs problem.

Comment: @TheDark hmm look, `i` is the position to insert at in the first array, right? While `range` is the size of the second array, which  we want to index from 0 to `range`. Try with e.g. `i == 10` and `a.size() == range == 5`.

Comment: @iksemyonov That's what I meant by "homework", as you say you can only "guess" that this is for learning purposes, but if it isn't then the correct answer is "throw it away and use `std::vector`".

Comment: Ha, one more in the last loop, look closely!

Comment: @TheDark nevermind you right, of course! Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: OK, I'm writing an answer with these two, though I bet they're not all there is.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so while we don't have all the code for the method being discussed, nor the `dynamic_array::shift_right()` code, I've noticed two mistakes right off the bat (thanks to @TheDark for nitpicking on my fix):

First one:

```
for (int m = i; m < range; m++) { new_array[m] = a[m]; }
```

Should be

```
for (int m = i; m < range + i; m++) { new_array[m] = a[m - i]; }
//                        ^^^                            ^^^
```

Another one of the same kind in the last, shifting loop:

```
for (int z = i; z < range; z++) { array[z] = a[z]; }
```

Should be:

```
for (int z = i; z < range + i; z++) { array[z] = a[z - i]; }
//                        ^^^                        ^^^
```

In fact, these may be causing a crash on trying to access `a[]` out of bounds. On a side note, that's one of the reasons why it's better, namely safer, to use iterators than simple integer indices for container access.

I didn't like this either:

```
int blocks_needed = (size) / BLOCK_SIZE;
if (size % 5 > 0) {
    blocks_needed = blocks_needed + 1;   //add a block if needed
}
```

This looks very much like hand-writing the [`ceil()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ceil/) function. Other than that, `5` apparently should equal `BLOCK_SIZE`, else this makes little sense to me. Thus, replace `5` with `BLOCK_SIZE` or better yet switch to `ceil()`.

Now on to the allocation-related errors. Here's one:

```
int blocks_needed = (size) / BLOCK_SIZE;

int blocks_needed = (size + range) / BLOCK_SIZE;
//                        ^^^^^^^
```

And here's another, while not really an error, but it's suboptimal behavior nonetheless:

```
if (size + range >= allocated_size) { //new space needed

if (size + range > allocated_size) { //new space needed
//              ^^^
```

Comment: Still not working. I'm not sure if it is the same output as before but I do know that it's not what I want. I updated my code to include the shift right function. The other problem might actually be the int blocks_needed part because what that's supposed to do figure out if there needs to be more allocated space. For example if there's an array with 4 elements and 16 elements are inserted then 3 memory blocks (or 15 new slots) would need to be allocated. Would that be causing this incorrect output?

Comment: Well, logically, it only allocates memory. The actual elements are defined by the copying and shifting loops, aren't they?

Comment: Also, "I'm not sure" has no place in programming. You should inspect the results closely, always, programming is a precise science.

Comment: Yes that's what it's supposed to do but like I said in the output the allocated size has been wrong a few times. I'm wondering if the allocated size is not being set correctly at the end when I update the sizes or if the memory allocation is not correct.

Comment: Also I said "I'm not sure" because the output is actually extremely long and I have the tools to tell if the output is the same as the expected output but if it's not then it's difficult to actually find the specific differences.

Comment: Once again. Read what I said above. Memory is just the **space** for your array elements. Which element goes where is defined by only the loops!

Comment: Alright, then test on short examples by hand, can you do that? E.g. arrays of length 1 to 5.

Comment: Again, I do understand what it's doing. The problem is after inspecting my code I can't seem to figure out why the allocated size is wrong. Again, I 100% understand that re-allocating the memory is just creating new space and I need to put the values in the array via those for loops. You don't need to explain that to me because I do understand how that works. What I don't understand is why I continue to get the wrong output. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: I am testing with short arrays. One of them returned the correct array and the right size but the allocated size was 5 and should have been 10. Another array I tested on gave me the correct allocated size but the array was 1 0 2 4 and it should've been 1 3 2 4 so I don't know where that extra 0 came from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102862/discussion-between-iksemyonov-and-josh-susa).